# SELECT query return 1 row from each group

Tags: mysql, sql, select, greatest-n-per-group

This is a product table and have few million of records.
[image]

I want to list record as below:
Normally I use:

```
SELECT id, 
       product_name, 
       store_id 
FROM product
GROUP BY store_id 
ORDER BY id.
```

Currently having SQL performance issue. I need SQL query to output result like this.

[image]

Comment: Please post the table structures and the output of the explain statement as part of the question so we can see WHY query is so slow. Make sure to include indexes in table definition.

Comment: mention your table name in query "from product"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are many alternatives to solves this, one which I recommend is to have joined a subquery which separately gets the latest `ID` (*assuming that the column is `AUTO_INCREMENT`ed*) for each `store_ID`.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  store_ID, MAX(ID) max_ID
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP BY store_ID
        ) b ON a.store_ID = b.store_ID AND
                a.ID = b.max_ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba920/1)

for better performance, be sure to have an index on these columns: `ID` and `store_id`.

**UPDATE 1**

if you want to have limit for every records, use this below,

```
SELECT ID, product_Name, store_ID
FROM   tableName a
WHERE
  (
     SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM   tableName b
     WHERE  b.store_ID = a.store_ID AND b.ID >= a.ID
  ) <= 2;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba920/5)

Comment: Great. But can I sort ID DESC?

Comment: ok. I noticed its using filesort in Execution Plan. How to improve SELECT performance?

Comment: do you have index on `ID` and `store_id`? can you add the result of this statement? `DESC tablename`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT store_id,id,product_name FROM table_name
WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_name GROUP BY store_id)
ORDER BY id
```

this should work and you can Order by as per your req either by store_id or id.

Comment: @J-W: How does this differ from the accepted answer (apart from syntax)? It seems that the results are correct in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try this please:

```
SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE B
JOIN (SELECT MAX(ID) MX FROM YOURTABLE GROUP BY STORE_ID) A
ON  A.STORE_ID = B.STORE_ID
AND B.ID = A.MX
GROUP BY B.STORE_ID
;
```