# ORDER BY p.display_order and i.img show thumbnail with specific image order

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to get product thumbnails on a product category page, each product 1st thumbnail image needs to be shown. right now the last image is showing.
here is the screen shot for my db structure

EDIT:

right now the table format as screenshot, there are 4 images with order 1,2,3,4 i want to get the image with img_order 1.

[image]

when i am running sql query

```
 SELECT i.img_order,p.*, i.product_id, i.dirName, i.img FROM products p inner JOIN product_images i ON i.product_id = p.id WHERE p.status = 1 and i.product_id=329 AND i.type = 'Static' GROUP BY i.product_id ORDER BY i.img_order asc
```

it's giving wrong result see screenshot

[image]

but i want to get the image with img_order 1.

Comment: screen shot is not clear enough, column name is not displayed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375099/select-query-return-1-row-from-each-group  this may help you.

Comment: We can't see the columns. Provide proper DDLs and a desired result instead

Comment: Or see something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882073/mysql-select-max-date-inside-a-join-statement/17882188#17882188

Comment: Please review edits @Strawberry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with the following sql query:

```
SELECT i.img_order,p.*, i.product_id, i.dirName, i.img FROM products p inner JOIN product_images i ON i.product_id = p.id WHERE p.status = 1 and i.product_id=329 AND i.type = 'Static' GROUP BY i.product_id ORDER BY i.img_order asc
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Something like this:

```
SELECT pi.img_order,p.*, pi.product_id, pi.dirName, pi.img 
FROM product as p
LEFT JOIN product_image as pi ON pi.product_id = p.id
JOIN
 ( SELECT id,product_id, MIN(img_order) minVal
   FROM product_image GROUP BY product_id
 ) i
ON pi.img_order = i.minVal AND i.id = pi.id;
```

fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/213ff/3)

Comment: @Umer bin Siddique check now!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like this.

**Check all the rows**

```
 $query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

 foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
 {
    echo $row['title'];
    echo $row['name'];
    echo $row['body'];
  }
```

Comment: You can store the values in array in the foreach loop if you want to return it.

Comment: i have tried this but some images are showing there 1st and some showing last

Comment: can you a little explain